# give a detailed proof of the following inequality for all integers n > 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

a) give a detailed proof of the following inequality for all integers n > 1
$$ \frac{{2}^{n}}{n} \leq {n \choose \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}$$

> This is what I have so far:
> $$\frac{{2}^{n}}{n} \leq {n \choose \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}$$
> $$ {n} \frac{{2}^{n}}{n} \leq {n}{n \choose \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}$$
> $$ \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} {n \choose k} \leq {n}{n \choose \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} $$
>
> How do I finish this?

b) give a detailed proof of the following inequality for all integer n $\geq$ 1
$$ \sqrt{{n}^{n}} \leq n! $$

> This is what I have so far:
> $$ \sqrt{{n}^{n}} \leq n! $$
> $$ {n}^{\frac{n}{2}} \leq {n}\times{(n - 1)}\times{...}\times{2}\times{1} $$
> $$ {n}^{\frac{n}{2}}\times{...}\times{n}^{\frac{n}{2}} \leq {n}\times{(n - 1)}\times{...}\times{2}\times{1} $$
> length of $\frac{n}{2} \leq$ length of n
>
> I have shown that the length is less, but how do I show it is less overall?

Comment: One thing you should not do is start with what you are trying to prove and see what follows. You can do that to explore things, but the eventual argument must go from known to desired.

Comment: It looks like you have to use induction. Are you familiar with induction?

Comment: Simplify the ratios $\frac{\binom{n}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$ as much as possible and try to figure out which $k$ yields the largest $\binom{n}{k}$. You still have to jiggle it a little, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

a) Because the "middle" binomials are the largest one
$$1=\binom{n}{0}<\binom{n}{1}<\dots<\binom{n}{\left \lfloor n/2 \right \rfloor}=\binom{n}{\left \lceil n/2 \right \rceil}>\dots>\binom{n}{n-1}>\binom{n}{n}=1$$
so we have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For a), you just need the fact ${n\choose k}\leq{n\choose\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ for all $0\leq k\leq n$. To see this, suppose $n$ is even and $k<n/2$, then

\begin{align}
{n\choose n/2}&={n\choose k}\times\frac{n-k}{k+1}\times\frac{n-k-1}{k+2}\times\cdots\times\frac{n/2+1}{n/2}\\[.8em]
&\geq{n\choose k}\times\frac{n/2+1}{n/2}\times\frac{n/2+1}{n/2}\times\cdots\times\frac{n/2+1}{n/2}\geq{n\choose k}.
\end{align}
The situation for $k>n/2$ is exactly reversed, and you can easily use the same arguments for odd $n$.

---

For b), you can easily show $(n-m)(m+1)\geq n$ for all integer $0\leq m<n$. Then again assume $n$ is even, we have

$$n^{n/2}=\prod_{m=0}^{n/2-1}n\leq\prod_{m=0}^{n/2-1}(n-m)(m+1)=n!.$$

For odd $n$, use the same idea with the bound $\sqrt n\leq(n+1)/2$.